# Escaping parameters in iOS Apple App Store Download Link

Tags: ios, app-store, appdelegate

Is it possible to escape parameters in an app store download link? If so, how?

My intended usage: My application lets existing users invite their friends to join. When they invite a friend, they provide some information about the friend (name, email) and a download link is sent to the friend's email.

When this invited friend clicks the link, and downloads the app for the first item, I would like to be able to detect that the user has downloaded the app from an invite, and have him skip the regular onboarding flow and go to a different onboarding screen where his information (name, email) is already prefilled.

If I could escape a string into the app store download link, I would be able to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible.
You can add parameters to a download link but it is essentially to track advertising / campaign performance. Those params will no be passed to the app at installation / first launch.

Nicolas